# python schedule, execute every 30 minutes based on os time

Tags: python, schedule

I'm running a crawler every 30 minutes using Python Schedule, and I want my crawler to run at an exact 30 min interval which is calculated based on the **system's time(ex mac, windows, linux).**

Below is my code, and it is being delayed by a minute every time it is executed.

```
schedule.every(30).minutes.do(crawl)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Throw the program inside of a while loop; while True: if time.round() mod 30 == 0 then crawl

Comment: Take a look at cronjobs, I think that's a better way to run something on schedule

Comment: @Mark I looked into it, but it was too hard to do it in the EC2 instance.

Comment: If you're not already too overwhelmed, here is a guide: https://www.cumulations.com/blog/how-to-write-cron-jobs-on-amazon-web-servicesaws-ec2-server/

Answer (score 1):

The argument for time.sleep is in seconds. So at most you should be 1 second off. Not one minute. If you're off by 1 minute, that is probably the time it takes to execute `crawl`

From the [docs](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#run-a-job-every-x-minute), you can use the [`at`](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#schedule.Job.at) function to run a job at a specific time. I don't think it will work for every 1/2 hour, though. So I think you might need *two* jobs

```
schedule.every().hour.at(':00').do(crawl)
schedule.every().hour.at(':30').do(crawl)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```